# What's wrong with my code when I scroll down the result with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

As the below demo, When I **drag** the mouse to the `Week` and I can't scroll to see the **final** `<li>` in the HTML's block and this might not run smoothly as well. I don't know what's wrong here, please take a look on it and let me know to how modify this.

**<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/huydq91/84X59/)</kbd>**

---

**HTML:**

```
<div class="yearly">2014
<div class="container">
    <ul class="ca-menu"></ul>
</div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".yearly").mouseover(function () {
    var num_month = 48;
    var current_year = 2014;
    for (i = num_month; i >= 1; i--) {
        $(".ca-menu").after("<li class='weekly'><a href='/Lists/ChartIndex.aspx?Week=" + i + "&Year=" + current_year + "'>Week " + i + "</a></li>");
    }
})
    .mouseout(function () {
    $(".weekly").hide();
});

});
```

Comment: I was able to scroll down to the last li...or I didn't understand your problem correctly

Comment: I was also able to see the last li...

Comment: It happens only when the mouse is over anchor <a> tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are not being able to scroll to the bottom is because when you hover over the `<li>` links, mouseover event is repeatedly called.
Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $(".yearly").hover(function () {
        console.log('yahh');
        var num_month = 48;
        var current_year = 2014;
        for (i = num_month; i >= 1; i--) {
            $(".ca-menu").after("<li class='weekly'><a href='/Lists/ChartIndex.aspx?Week=" + i + "&Year=" + current_year + "'>Week " + i + "</a></li>");
        }
    },
       function () {
        $(".weekly").hide();
    });

        });
```

Comment: Thank you for your code. That fixed my problem well :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is because you keep on creating the `<li>` when your mouse move over.

make your `<li>` list outside the mouse over function. Then just show and hide it with respective mouse event:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        var num_month = 48;
        var current_year = 2014;
        for (i = num_month; i >= 1; i--) {
            $(".ca-menu").after("<li class='weekly'><a href='/Lists/ChartIndex.aspx?Week=" + i + "&Year=" + current_year + "'>Week " + i + "</a></li>");
        }
    $(".weekly").hide();
    $(".yearly").mouseover(function () {
        $(".weekly").show();
    })
        .mouseout(function () {
        $(".weekly").hide();
    });

});
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhyap/84X59/3/)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. However, it doesn't seem to run well when I drag the mouse over the `Week` and scroll down and then... it didn't work.